# Override a property with CSS variable only if that variable is declared

Tags: html, css, css-variables

I have a `flex` box and I also want it to be hidden (`display: none !important`) only if a variable is set.

```css
.d-flex {
  display: flex; /*Set by Bootstrap library*/
}

.my-item {
  display: var(--display); /*Should only apply if --display is set*/
}

.container.hide-items {
  --display: none !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="d-flex my-item">Flexbox 1 (not hidden)</div>
  <div class="d-flex my-item">Flexbox 2 (not hidden)</div>
</div>

<div class="container hide-items">
  <div class="d-flex my-item">Flexbox 1 (hidden)</div>
  <div class="d-flex my-item">Flexbox 2 (hidden)</div>
</div>
```

The above code only works when `hide-items` exists but when `--display` is undefined, the browser just falls back into (probably) `inline`. I know `var()` accepts fallback values but I do not know how to set it so the element stays to whatever it was set before (in this case `flex`), I have tried `unset` or `initial` but they don't get their `flex` value back. Is this possible?

[image]

Comment: Once you drop the CSS `property: value`, you redefine it no matter was it defined in the other selector or not (if the `value` is valid and your current selector has greater specificity). Still you can use the `var(--variable-name, default-value)` syntax to set the default value if the `--variable-name` was not defined. In your case that could be: `display: var(--display, flex);` or `display: var(--display, inherit);`. The latter will not take the value from another definition, but will inherit parent element's `display` value.

Answer (score 0):

You will I think have to 'repeat' the Bootstrap flex setting.

This snippet sets the --display variable to flex for `.container .d-flex.my-item` elements and then sets it to none for `.container.hide-items .d-flex.my-item`

```css
.d-flex {
  display: flex; /*Set by Bootstrap library*/
}

.container .d-flex.my-item {
  display: var(--display);
}
.container  .d-flex.my-item {
  --display: flex;
}
.container.hide-items .d-flex.my-item {
  --display: none !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="d-flex my-item">Flexbox 1 (not hidden)</div>
  <div class="d-flex my-item">Flexbox 2 (not hidden)</div>
</div>

<div class="container hide-items">
  <div class="d-flex my-item">Flexbox 1 (hidden)</div>
  <div class="d-flex my-item">Flexbox 2 (hidden)</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I see, that's unfortunate! Thanks though